# Consuming WCF service in Xamarin WIndows Phone project

Tags: wcf, xamarin.forms

I have a bit of a problem with my Xamarin.Forms project. I have generated web service proxy class with SlSvcutil.exe and have imported that class in my PCL library that is shared amongs platform specific projects / iOs, Android and WindowsPhone.

All the references from System.ServiceModel are missing because, ofcourse, that reference does not exist in my project. How do I add it? I tried to do it with NuGet but it just fails all the time with same error.

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried selecting 'Ignore All' for Dependacy Behavior when installing package but to no avail.

This is driving me crazy as I have so much problems with this Xamarin and I havent really started programming yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to install an extra package. Just add `System.ServiceModel`, `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.Xml` to your references. If you need to, you can just open your csproj file in a text editor and add these to the same area where you see other references in the file:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
```

And make sure that you are using slsvcutil.exe from the Silverlight 5 SDK, not an older one. Taking a look at a working WCF client in one of our projects, I see this exact tool version:

```
// This code was auto-generated by SlSvcUtil, version 5.0.61118.0
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the solution. As I've learned WCF proxy client is NOT supported on Windows Phone 8.1. I do not know if this is case with Windows Phone 8.